# Windows App Keeps changing time randomly

Tags: windows, time, ntp, time-zone

I faced a time problem this week, i have a Network camera app that runs based on multiple servers. the servers storage is where the camera recordings go.

Now everything was fine since the first installtion until now where the time keeps changing and it affects the app, no live view works and the recording stops until the time gets back to normal again.

This is the event log i found [Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf6Bd.jpg)

Note that system_manager is the service that runs the link between the app,server and cameras.

I disabled NTP server inside the app but it doesn't work. [NTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZKmE.jpg)

I tried to set a script to change time every 5 min based on a google time server but it doesn't solve the problem, the whole thing just gets messy.

Now my question is how do i stop this service from changing the time, is there a registry entry that disables getting time from outside sources?

Comment: Which app is that? Is this inside a domain

Comment: This looks like it might be related to the recent changes to/from summer time

Comment: Ssm Console it's a wisenet camera software and no it's just a flat workgroup

Comment: Yes David the moment the summer time changed the whole thing collapsed

Answer (score 0):

I think i might just have found a way out but i'm not sure yet will check the next day for changes.

Basically i set the firewall outbound rule to block outgoing connexions for the exe that is changing the time, And for now things are going well but the downside is that there are some issue with the app although they're not major issues but i need a better solution.